# Where to find average man/woman drawings as proposed by Quetelet?

Tags: statistics

Where to find average man/woman drawings as proposed by [Adolphe Quetelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolphe_Quetelet)? Drawings along the years would be very nice. He proposed the idea of average man in 1835 (see https://historyofinformation.com/detail.php?entryid=2154). To see how the "average man evolved from 1835 would be nice!

Comment: @Mauricio, i've included the requested ingo.

Comment: Could you be more specific at to where Quetelet proposed such drawings? I assume the question is related to the following book: Adolphe Quetelet, *Sur l'homme et le développement des ses facultés, Vol. 2.* Paris: Bachelier 1835. ([scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sur_l_homme_et_le_d%C3%A9veloppement_de_ses/WXsIAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP9&printsec=frontcover)) in particular chapter 1 of book 4 on pp. 250-293 where he discusses at some length *propriétés de l'homme moyen* (properties of the average man).

Comment: at Cleveland Museum there are two statues based in the quetelet idea: https://www.cabinetmagazine.org/issues/15/cambers.php

Answer (score 3):

Not drawings but statues at Cleveland Museum: The final measure is the mean of 3,863 measurements of American citizens:
curious? take a look at: https://www.cabinetmagazine.org/issues/15/cambers.php

Beyond the Average Man: The Art of Unlikelihood
Roger Koenker
University of Illinois, Urbana-Champaign
FEMES/Taipei: July, 2007
[http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/AvMan/femes.pdf](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eroger/research/AvMan/femes.pdf)

it seems there are no drawings in the original Quetelet book. howevwe in its

I've found this in Anthropométrie ou mesure des différentes facultés de l'homme(https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1513441w.image)

[image]

this book Adolphe Quetelet, Social Physics and the
Average Men of Science, 1796–1874 by  Kevin Donnelly,displays this picture:

[image]